# Fetched from upstream eclipse github: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, git, github, classnotfoundexception, egit

I'm trying to revert to a previous commit. I'm using Juno eclipse and github/egit.

Reverting works: I can see my old code. But when I try to run it, I get this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mmPackage/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mmPackage.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Exception in thread "main"

My package is called mmPackage.

This exact code worked for me when I pushed it to github a few days ago. Now that I've revered to a previous commit, it just can't seem to find my class with a main method!

I have tried:

- Building project
- Making sure my src folder is in the build path

I also noticed my bin folder does not seem to contain any .class files. I tried deleting it using the file system browser and re-running, but no luck. And now I can't even see a bin folder in my file system!

Thank you!

Comment: What command did you use when you say 'reverting works'?